# How to bind data in an item control to stack panel?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a custom ListBox. That receives a list with three properties:

SubjectName
Problems
AverageScore

The property Problems is another list which contains several Problem class. This is the data template I'm creating.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SubjectDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProblemNumber, FallbackValue=ProblemNumber}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SubjectName, FallbackValue=SubjectName}" Padding="3,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AverageScore, FallbackValue=AverageScore}" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Problems}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Background="Aqua" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="20" Width="20" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Role, FallbackValue=Role}" />-->
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

But I've got a problem trying to show Problems data. I'm trying to show each element from Problems list in a stack panel with ortientation horizontal, but I get each stack panel separated.

[image]

I need to put the red rectangles inside the stack control. For example, the ten rectangles from Times Tables should be in one only stack panel.

**UPDATE 1:**

Something like this:

[image]

According to the graph, the first stack panel (background aqua) must contain 10 red rectangles.

UPDATE 2:

I'm verifying showing the data from problem in a textBlock and it works:

```
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Problems}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsCorrect}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>


                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Gainsboro" Margin="5" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use nested ItemsControls - One for the Vertical list and one for the  Horizontal List.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Problems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Problems}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Height="20" Width="20" Margin="1,0">
                            <Rectangle.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCorrect}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Rectangle.Style>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Background="Aqua" Margin="5" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: You did it Rachel! One more thing: Problems contains an property called IsCorrect (boolean). I'd like to show a red rectangle when the property will be false, and blue when that one is true

Comment: @oscar.fimbres Use a DataTrigger for that in the Rectangle style. See my edit.

Comment: But I have a doubt, isn't it necessary to extract the class Problem from Problems?

Comment: @oscar.fimbres Change your DataTrigger to `Problem.IsCorrect` then

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I'm a newbie in WPF. Is it a problem that problems are a List<Problem>? Because it's still appearing always red rectangles.

Comment: @oscar Does your class look like `Subject.Problems[x].Problem.IsCorrect`, or `Subject.Problems[x].Problems[x].IsCorrect`, or `Subject.Problems[x].IsCorrect`?

Comment: Problems[x].IsCorrect   from   Problems<List>

Comment: So to access the `IsCorrect` property of an item you would be going `Subject.Problems[0].Problems[0].IsCorrect`? See my like... 10th edit to my answer lol. You need to use nested ItemsControls if this is the case.

Comment: What am I supposed to write where it says: ProblemSubList? Problem?

Comment: Please, check my update Rachel.. I passing the last code in a textBox and it show the values, it's right.

But intead of use the textblock, using the rectangles doesn't work. Alway set red rectangles.

Comment: I've fixed the error of styles. We should eliminate this line:
<Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="1,0">

And thanks, I actually appreciate your help.

Comment: @oscar Yes, I forgot to remove the old `Fill="Red"` property of the Rectangle when the style got added, and properties set within the control tag overwrite the ones set in the style.

Answer (score 0):

In your ItemsControl.ItemsPanel make the StackPanel orientation Horizoantal

Comment: OK, but just move the red rectangle to left

Comment: try in your ItemsControl to set HorizontalContentAlignment to Left

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

UPDATED:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SubjectDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Margin="5">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProblemNumber, FallbackValue=ProblemNumber}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SubjectName, FallbackValue=SubjectName}" Padding="3,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AverageScore, FallbackValue=AverageScore}" />
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Problems}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="20" Width="20" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel  Background="Aqua" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: no, it's still showing the red rectangles in each stack panel

Comment: Sorry I guess I'm a little confused on what you are trying to accomplish.